# Python: Pandas plot histogram with centered x-values

Tags: python, pandas, histogram

I want to plot the distribution of the following [dataset](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9w02xbmm2bmhj45/histo.csv?dl=0) (column `maxnet`).

If I do the following in Python using Pandas DataFrame:

`df['maxnet'].hist(bins=10,range=(5,11), grid=False, alpha=0.3, histtype="stepfilled")`

I get the following figure:

[image]

As you can see, I don't have the x-axis values centered under each bar. I want the x-values (6, 7, 8, 9, 10) to be centered under the bar. How can I do that?

Also, if I want to change the x-axis label for (Dec6, Dec7, Dec8, Dec9, Dec10), still centered under each bar, how can I do that?

Comment: What is your data?  Each bar represents one bin, so where the bars are depends on what the bins are.  It would be misleading to put the tick marks in the middle of the bars if the bins aren't centered on those values.

Comment: basically, I want to graph the number of occurrence of the number 6, 7, 8, 9, and 10 in the dataset.

Comment: For that, if the dataset has a relatively small number of distinct values, you might be better off using `df['maxnet'].value_counts()` to get the frequency of each value, then use that to make a bar plot.

Comment: Very good question, I have checked the pandas documentation page, no clue. Even the demo plot is broken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the suggestion of BrenBarn, I was able solve my problem. Here's my solution:

`bar = pd.DataFrame(maxdf['maxnet'].value_counts())
bar = bar.sort()
bar.plot(kind='bar')`